# C# Assigning one button to another

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have a GUI app, that has a button added.  Within several plugin dll's, a new button is created and needs to be added to the GUI in place of the existing one.

Is there a way to simply say ButtonA = ButtonB?  Or do I have to remove the button from the GUI at runtime and then add the new one?

Thanks.

Comment: You can just change the event handler method for the existing button. A button is a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can just link it to another handler, something like:

your old Click event handler

```
private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Do sth
}
```

your new Click Event handler (like if you create a new button)

```
private void ButtonB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Do sth
}
```

then you need to remove the first handler and add your new handler:

```
ButtonA.Click -= this.ButtonA_Click;
ButtonA.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonB_Click);
```

Answer (score 1):

You button is added to some parent (the Form for example). That means you have to remove the original button from the Form's Controls collection, and add the new button. Or, you can replace the button inside the Controls collection.

Let's say after iterating through the collection, you find that the button is the 5'th element, you can do something like this:

```
this.Controls[4] = ButtonB;
```

I'm not 100% sure if this means that you will have to manually invalidate the screen to update the GUI. In that case call `ButtonB.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

Copy properties you are interested in from the first button to the second that is created, and then either remove first button from the Controls collection or set .Visible to false.

As for events, you'll have problem there, because you'll have to call old button event handlers manually - there is no way in .NET to read OnClick (or any other event) subscribers.